# Store objects in Android

Tags: android

I would like to know what would be the best option to store a custom Java object that I have in my application. I've read about serialization but it seems to be quite slow.

What is the best option?

Comment: Have you tried [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best method for saving data - preferences, sqlite, serializable or other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962426/best-method-for-saving-data-preferences-sqlite-serializable-or-other)

Comment: "custom Java object" could be anything in terms of data complexity and size. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 16):

If you're not storing an over abundance of data you can use Gson to convert a Java object to a Json string and store the string in your app preferences.  Gson has a toJson(obj) method and visa-vis.

Getting data out of app preferences and into an object:

```
String json = appSharedPrefs.getString("someName","");    
return gson.fromJson(json, YourModel.class);
```

To get data from your object into app preferences:

```
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Then `prefsEditor.putString("someName", json).apply()`.

Comment: Could you please post a reference link or code sample? Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem.  That has been very handy ;)

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to sleep more often but I am having an issue using this in my Android project. Do I need to manually include the JAR for Gson (if so, where can I find it?) or am I missing something for the import (using Eclipse, cannot resolve the package com.google) - thanks. @Bill

Comment: Yes.  GSON is an external library you have to add.  Google it.  Don't recall the exact URL.

Comment: Thanks again, @Bill. I just needed a slap on the back of the head and some sleep! The URL is: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Comment: It's too late, but maybe can read this: You should use Maven or Gradle, they're very good options instead of download jar files, then adding to your project. Maven and Gradle do this automatically

Comment: At the time of this answer @Antonio maven for Android was HORRIBLE and Gradle wasn't an option.  Today, however, as you point out, there are many better ways to handle adding a JAR or AAR to your project ;)

Answer (score 5):

You should read:

1. [Best method for saving data - preferences, sqlite, serializable or other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962426/best-method-for-saving-data-preferences-sqlite-serializable-or-other)
2. [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)