# Specifying a filepath

Tags: java, android, filepath

I recently started my first app (for a psychology study) and I want to create .txt files which will record the participants' answers. (but for now it's just a test file with only one line "this is a test file")

My first problem is that I can't find the file that is supposed to be created. I get no error so I suppose it *is* created somewhere.

I have read that the files might be in "data/data" folder, which apparently I can't access without rooting my phone (I would like to avoid that).

So my question is, **how can I modify the path** so the file is created in the Downloads folder or anywhere that I can access? I tried using `this.getExternalFilesDir(null)`, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, `Context.getFilesDir()` but I can't find my file on the local storage or on the SD card.

I did add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest but I don't know if I need to do something else. For instance, I don't know if I have to create a folder for my app (like those com.domain.app folders) of if it's supposed to do it automatically.

Thanks! I know similar questions have been posted but so far I couldn't find an answer that works for me. If I didn't mention something important, don't hesitate to point it out because my guess is I forgot something really basic.

Comment: You can always provide a full path to create the file. On a side note: use a database to store data, not txt files.

Comment: @m0skit0 Thanks, I'll look into that. Since there will not be much data, I thought txt files would have been enough and simpler.

Comment: The duplicate should help with your `this.getExternalFilesDir(null)` and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` problems. Beyond that, you might consider providing a [mcve], and you might be interested in learning more about [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question but I thought it might be worth mentioning [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), which tends to be simplest way to store application data, especially since you mentioned there won't be that much data being stored.

SharedPreferences allows you to store key/value pairs using methods like [putString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Note that modifying the shared preferences must be done on the SharedPreferences editor.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Save answer
// Don't forget to call apply() at the end, or commit() to block until the write is complete
sharedPrefs.edit().putString("KEY_TO_ANSWER_1", "My answer").apply();
// Read answer
sharedPrefs.getString("KEY_TO_ANSWER_1", "Default value if not found");
```

If you're using a good amount of these across your application it helps to keep it all together. This is a pattern I find myself using quite often:

```
public enum Preferences {

    INSTANCE;

    private static final String PREFS_A1 = "answer1";

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE.mPrefs == null) {
            INSTANCE.mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        return INSTANCE.mPrefs;
    }

    public static void setAnswer1(Context context, String answer) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(PREFS_A1, answer).apply();
    }

    public static String getAnswer1(Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).getString(PREFS_A1, "No answer provided");
    }

    public static void clearAnswer1(Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().remove(PREFS_A1).apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks convenient but since it's for a study, multiple people will use the app (we will record data on one phone, one participant at a time). If I understand correctly, everytime someone answers a question, this would erase the answers from the previous participants? Or is it possible to create the preferences in a loop, like sharedPrefsID1, sharedPrefsID2, etc?

Comment: Correct, this setup would overwrite the value each time. Looping them with IDs like you suggested would work, but it might be cleaner to use a StringSet. This will allow you save multiple answers to each question. Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195164/android-setting-and-fetching-a-stringset-from-sharedpreferences (requires API 11+)

Comment: Another approach, though a little more work, would be to serialize a more complex object that will allow you to easily combine multiple answers, such as a JSON or even a CSV (depending on what exactly you would be storing), however at that point it might be easier just to use a SQLite database.